# HDMI output not working on new MacBook Pro 2016 Touch Bar

Tags: usb, hdmi

I am trying to get HDMI output working (both on tv and my normal HD screen) from my new mac. The device only has USB-C ports, so I bought two types of converters (not official from Apple, but didn't think that would matter):

- [This adapter](http://www.lazada.sg/usb-31-type-c-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter-cable-black-14cm-10525602.html?utm_source=Orderconfirmation&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=LineItem), that I use with a regular hdmi cable.
- [This adapter with integrated cable](http://www.lazada.sg/3m-mhl-usb-31-type-c-to-hdmi-1080p-hdtv-cable-adapter-for-phonestablets-5194527.html?utm_source=Orderconfirmation&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=LineItem).

None are recognised by the Mac. I've tried hitting the option key and detecting displays, but none show. I've also tried plugging in the usb cable that is attached to the last cable in the tv too, no luck. I see that the first adapter has a power slot too, I can try to plug in a usb power source there?

I've also just updated Sierra, no luck.

Any other suggestions? My vga / usb-c adapter works fine.

Is there any logfile or so that I could check to see if the device gets recognised?

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor/TV?  How about a different adapter?

Comment: I tried two monitors and two adapters

Comment: One more question....how do you "just upgrade to Sierra" on a MBP 2016 when by default it comes with it and you can't downgrade to anything else?

Comment: I didn't 'just upgrade to Sierra', but upgraded Sierra, as in updated to the last version.

Comment: Did you fix your problem? I bought hub usb-c multiports and HDMI doesn't work on Mac OS but it does on Windows from bootcamp. The Anker one works?

Comment: I can't order the Anker here in Singapore. Will get it next month when I am in the US and will check back in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on everything you have described, it sounds like the problem is between your MBP and the TV(s).  I am not a fan of no-name adapters like the one you linked in your question.

I have personally recommended this [Anker USB-C to HDMI adapter](http://radnex.us/anker_usb-c_HDMI_4K) to a family member with excellent results.

[image]

It's got high ratings, an 18 month warranty and supports 4K at 60Hz.  The adapters you referenced didn't support that level of resolution (1080p looked to be the max).

Comment: Good point. I did get an Anker usb hub that seems to work well so will try. Is there a reason to get the official apple one or should Anker work?

Comment: I hardly use "official" Apple adapters based mostly on their build quality - the better 3rd party manufacturers seem to do a better job.  The plus side to using "official" Apple is that you have one place to look when things go wrong.

Comment: I've been trying to find some place to order anker, but alas, since moving from London to Singapore last month online shopping has taken a step back... Any suggestions for other brands?

Comment: What about [StarTech](https://tr.im/StartTech_USBC_HDMI) or [TrendNet](https://tr.im/TrendNet_USB_HDMI)?  I have used both brands from time to time, but (disclaimer) I have never used either of these particular adapters.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. Still a bit wary given that I already tried two though.

Comment: I had to wait until I visited the US to buy this one, but it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to replace adapter. It should work unless it is defective.

I read the instructions here...
https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201177

Just plug in your display to your MacBook Pro using your adapter and restart your Mac.  This is what worked for me.